# Inner join in hibernate SQL:

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have 2 tables:

1. Coupons (mapped in hibernate.cfg.xml as `"Coupon"`)
2. Businesses (mapped in hibernate.cfg.xml as `"Business"`)

Every row in `Business` have the following columns:

- Business_id
- latitude

Every row in `Coupon` have the following columns:

- ID
- Business_id (`Which business this coupon is relevant to?`)
- Expier_date

I want to get all the coupons that relevant to people in the area of 10KM.

So, I tried to get all coupons of businesses with `latitude < 30`.

```
    return (List<Coupon>) s.createQuery(
    "from Coupon inner join Business on business_id where Business.latitude < 30").list();
```

But getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 42 [from entities.Coupon inner join Business on business_id where Business.latitude < 30]
```

If I missed any necessary information, please let me know and I add it.

Using mySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a valid HQL query the word **on** is wrong. [View this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins). This maybe run:

```
from Coupon as c inner join c.business  as b where b.latitude < 30
```

[The relationship must be correctly mapped.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html#components-dependentobjects)

Comment: c.business means that in the class Coupon there are a property named business of type Business. If your class Copun have  any property of type Business, the relationship between the two tables is not mapped.

Comment: I don't have one. how do I add relationship? Should it be one-to-one?

Comment: The manual explain it(http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html), in your question the relationship seems one-to-many